# Spring boot login page issue - webpage not found error

Tags: java, spring-boot

i am making a spring boot login page.
controller code -

```
package controller;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import domain.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import service.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


//    @GetMapping("/login")
//
//    public ModelAndView login() {
//        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");
//        mav.addObject("user", new User());
//        return mav;
//    }

//    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
//    public String get(ModelMap model) {
//        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello, World!");
//        return "login";
//    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getUser(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("user", new User());

        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") User user ) {

        User oauthUser = userService.login(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());


        System.out.println(oauthUser);

        if(Objects.nonNull(oauthUser))
        {

            return "redirect:/";


        } else {
            return "redirect:/login";


        }

    }


}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to Home Page</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.2/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <style type="text/css">
<!--        #cen1{-->
<!--            margin-left: auto;-->
<!--            margin-right: auto;-->
<!--            margin-top: auto;-->
<!--            margin-bottom: auto;-->
<!--            background-color: green;-->
<!--        }-->

        body,td,th{
            color: #000000;
        }

        body{
            background-color: #F0F0F0;
        }

        .style1
        {
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 12px;
            line-height: 25px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            text-decoration: none;

        }

        .style2
        {
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 17px;
            padding: 12px;
            line-height: 25px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            text-decoration: none;

        }



    </style>

</head>

<body>
<!--<div id="cen1">-->
<div class="container">
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">
                <table class="table-bordered" width="350" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="#ffffff">

                    <form action="#" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${user}" method="post">


                        <tr>
                            <td height="25" colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="style2">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <strong>Student Login</strong>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Username</td>
                            <td>

                                <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" class="form-control"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password</td>
                            <td><input type="password" th:field="*{password}" class="form-control"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" align="right">Login</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </form>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<!--</div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lab7

server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
#spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false
#spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
#spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

server.port=8080
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

#logging.level.root=WARN

spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
api.base.path = http://localhost:8080/login
```

when i visit locahost:8080 i get the index.html page
but when i visit locallhost:8080/login i get error

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
```

if you need any more details i can add them but i think this is the majority portion which is producing error.
help!

main class

```
package com.example.Loginform;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LoginformApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoginformApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**edit

Comment: You didn't show your main class, but you're probably not scanning your controller class. (Note also that constructor injection is recommended instead of field injection, and that you should use Spring Security instead of inventing your own security code.)

Comment: please check now

Comment: you're certainly not scanning your controller class

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: There is something wrong with your package structure (component-scan). Ref: [structuring-your-code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.structuring-your-code.locating-the-main-class)

Comment: after changing project structure i get this HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error